# Should I store 90 rows of data for EVERY user (with millions of users)?

Tags: mysql, database

*I'm planning the structure of a MySql database and could use some advice from more seasoned professionals. The site which the DB belongs to gathers 90-days of weather data for EACH registered user, and has to support millions of users.*

I already have a table for the users, with their login and contact information, but assume that I need a second table for all the weather data...

What I intend to do is basically store the average temperature, humidity, wind-direction and so fourth - per day - for every user. And each day the DB is updated with the new day's data, while keeping yesterday's entries (but limited to 89-days of old data + the current day's data) - for all users.

Now, does it make most sense to have one huge "data" table that has 90 rows for EVERY user (with millions of users)? Or is there a more clever way to do this that is better for performance reasons or similar?

*The 90-days of data will be accessed (READ and displayed etc.) every time a user logs in and views his own profile or if she browses someone else's profile. But it will only be updated once per day (overwriting the oldest entry, maintaining the limit of 90 rows per user.)*

Comment: Is the weather data specific to users (they have a device that measures the data specifically? Or is it like city data, and you have 50000 users in one city? Thus the data is the same for different users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: saw just now that each user has different weather data. Keeping the "shared data" in the answer, but you're interested in the second case.

**Users share weather data**

Based, say, on their nearest weather station ID.

I'd store a (userId, stationId, isActive, isPreferred) table to know what data the user is interested in, and then I'd run a query against stationWeatherData to fetch the 90 rows of weather data for that station.

**Each user has his own weather data**

There shouldn't be particular problems in handling 900 million users. If you really had to, you could "shard" on different tables based on userId, e.g, table weather174 would hold data of all users for which (userId % 1000) gives 174, and you'd find yourself with 1000 tables - possibly on different servers - of one thousandth the size.

So you start with one big table, and prepare for sharding (or moving to cloud storage and a no-SQL keystore database, e.g. MongoDB, VoltDB). Or partition based on UserID as soon as UserID reaches, say, one million.

Or even, you don't use a database at all. A DB makes sense if you need to search or correlate/join data -- here you are just accessing a user's "weather station".

If you know you're never going to query "How many users have 60% humidity?", but always only "What data are there for user 1234567?", then you might save the data in a rolling buffer in binary, JSON or HTML format (on cloud storage, S3, or again MongoDB - now only one document per user). Much would then depend on how the data to be updated is arriving, i.e., in one big batch from a concentrator or each user uploading its own.

Answer (score 1):

For my answer (below), I assumed the data is specific to the user, such as from their personal backyard weather station.  If it is data shared with other users, then my answer is sub-optimal.

---

That seems reasonable, but why stop at 90 days?  Keep daily information for each user for as long as they are valid users.  The described query is always then something like

```
SELECT temperature_avg, humidity, wind_direction, wind_speed
FROM weather_summary
WHERE user_id = (current_user)
ORDER BY sample_date DESC
LIMIT 90;
```

As long as there are indexes on `sample_date` and `user_id`, this will be extremely efficient.

Having a separate table for each user has never worked out very well in my experience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! On to your question: I've been considering the 90-day limit simply to limit the size of the DB as it will have millions of users.

Comment: @user805220:  Don't sweat that there will be millions of users.  A sane schema for a hundred or a thousand is the same as for a billion.  Once you have a solid design, scaling it up is straightforward:  distributed, partitioned, etc.  The cost of storage is almost free.  Efficient access to it requires a little care, but is not difficult to master.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the location of each user, it would be simpler to store the weather data based on location and map it to the user on demand.

UserId --> LocationId --> Weather details.

Assuming that on the average there will be multiple users from each location, this should cut down on your database size quite a bit and should also scale better.

Comment: It's not per location (e.g. city), but per user though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a single table for the weather data, partitioned by the date (see [MySQL documentation on range partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html)).

This way, you can easily get rid of old data (simply drop the oldest partition), and queries for ranges of days (say, average temperature for the last 7 days) will be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Index on table columns (id, full-text indexing).
2. As an idea, you can create some views on this table that will contain filtered data on the basis of location, days, week, month or quarter or alphabets or other criteria and based on that your code will decide which view to use to fetch the search results.
3. OR if your table has much insert/update operations you can make more than one table and based on some criteria choose the table name to update/insert data with your server side programming language.